# Graph API filter query says "The specified filter to the reference property query is currently not supported."

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, microsoft-graph

I am displaying users from certain groups within an SPFx web part for SharePoint Online.

If I try to add a filter I get the error "The specified filter to the reference property query is currently not supported"

It works fine without the filter.

Thanks
P

```
let filterString = "jobTitle eq 'Partner'";
      let filterString = "startswith(mail, 'p')";
      let filterString = "givenName eq 'Pete'";


      var client = await this.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient('3');
      var result = await client.api('groups/' + this.properties.groupGUID + '/members').filter(filterString).get();
```

Comment: As per the documentation example, it should work: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-5-use-filter-to-get-group-membership-with-a-display-name-that-starts-with-the-letter-a-including-a-count-of-returned-objects

Answer (score 2):

As per official documentation for [List Members API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) you need to add custom header **ConsistencyLevel** with value "**eventual**" and also need to add query string parameter **$count** with value **true**

See details of [Request Header](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-headers)

> **ConsistencyLevel**: eventual. This header and $count are required when using the $search, $filter, $orderby, or OData cast query parameters. It uses an index that might not be up-to-date with recent changes to the object.

You can try below code to use filter in that api which is working in my case

```
var result = await client.api('groups/groupid/members').headers({
  "ConsistencyLevel":"eventual"
}).count(true).filter("startsWith(mail,'alex')").get();
```